# How to track down ServerXMLHTTP memory leaks / calls?

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2003, serverxmlhttp

We are monitoring the execution of database job using a in-house tool which requires an URL call after the job has been finished.

For our SQL jobs we use custom function (to be found [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/validate-a-url-from-sql-server.aspx)) that creates an `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0` Object to send the URL request.

Our job runs every 5 minutes, so there is a URL call roughly every 5 minutes.
Under SQL Server 2005 and Win2k3 this solution worked perfectly for some years.
After we have recently migrated the jobs to a SQL Server 2008 (Win2k3 also), this URL call works for roughly 3 days and then fails.
The solution to fix this is a reboot of the server (restarting the sql server service does not work), so I suggest some memory leak. However I do have no clue, how to debug this memory leak- there are no error messages in the event log or no log files, what so ever.

The code for the custom function (property of Adam Mechanic- see above) is:

```
BEGIN   
  DECLARE @Object INT
  DECLARE @Return TINYINT
  DECLARE @Valid BIT
  SET @Valid = 0 --default to false
  --create the XMLHTTP object
  EXEC @Return = sp_oacreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0', @Object OUTPUT 

  IF @Return = 0
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Method VARCHAR(350)
    --define setTimeouts method
    --Resolve, Connect, Send, Receive
    SET @Method = 'setTimeouts(45000, 45000, 45000, 45000)'
    --set the timeouts      
    EXEC @Return = sp_oamethod @Object, @Method

    IF @Return = 0
    BEGIN
      --define open method
      SET @Method = 'open("GET", "' + @URL + '", false)'
      --Open the connection
      EXEC @Return = sp_oamethod @Object, @Method
    END         

    IF @Return = 0      
    BEGIN   
      --SEND the request
      EXEC @Return = sp_oamethod @Object, 'send()'
    END     

    IF @Return = 0
    BEGIN           
      DECLARE @Output INT
      EXEC @Return = sp_oamethod @Object, 'status', @Output OUTPUT
      IF @Output = 200
      BEGIN         
        SET @Valid = 1
      END
    END
  END

  --destroy the object
  EXEC sp_oadestroy @Object
  RETURN (@Valid)
END
```

I have debugged it so far, that I know that

```
--define open method
SET @Method = 'open("GET", "' + @URL + '", false)'              
--Open the connection           
EXEC @Return = sp_oamethod @Object, @Method
```

fails.

Any clue is very much appreciated.